# How can I purge applications with the same BundleIDdentifier

Tags: swift, macos, bundle-identifier

I have been testing an application I am developing, but have come into a problem with the Bundle Identifier.

I had copied the application to a location for testing, and since deleted it. However, I find that when I try something like this:

```swift
//  Current Application
    let id = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
    let thisApp = NSRunningApplication.runningApplications(withBundleIdentifier: id).last!
//  Get Bundle
    let bundleURL = NSWorkspace.shared.urlForApplication(withBundleIdentifier: bundleID)!
    guard let bundle = Bundle(url: bundleURL)
    else {
        print("oops! bundleURL: \(bundleURL)")
        return
    }
```

I *usually* get the error message. It appears that `urlForApplication` us using the location of an old copy, since deleted, not the current location.

How can I find these past locations and remove them? The old copy of the application has already been deleted (and the bin emptied).

Comment: Where is the current location? The documentation for `urlForApplication` says "This method uses various (currently unspecified) heuristics in case multiple apps have the same bundle ID." Assuming that it somehow thinks the deleted app still exists, you need to move the application that you want to find to a location more desirable by its unspecified heuristic function. Try `/Applications`.

Comment: I’ve noticed that it’s in the `iCloud Drive (Archive)` folder, which must have been created when I was fiddling win the iCloud account. I’ll delete that particular location and see what happens. I was more worried about what happens if I have multiple versions I suppose.

Comment: That's a peculiar location for an application to be in... Is an application "installed" on your mac if it is actually on iCloud? I don't know. Or is the "iCloud Drive (Archive)" a local directory? I have never messed with iCloud before. Try moving it to `/Applications` and see if `urlForApplication` can find it.

Comment: `thisApp.bundleURL`

Comment: @Sweeper It’s still in the development stage, so I’m only running temporary copies of the application. The development folder is in the  iCloud drive for convenience. I did delete the (Archive) copy and that did solve the immediately problem, but I’m still worried about what happens if I test multiple versions with the same bundle id.

Comment: @Manngo In that case `urlForApplication` is a magic black box unfortunately :( You don't get to choose which URL you get.

Comment: @LeoDabus The current application is one of many I want to identify, but I suppose I could make an exception for it. The other applications don’t seem to have this problem, and I’ve only created the problem because of the testing versions.

Comment: @Sweeper That’s what it’s looking like. I might use @LeoDabus’ suggestion and make it a special case. Thanks.

Comment: `NSApplication.current.bundleURL` ? You can check if the url is not equal to the current one

Comment: @LeoDabus is `NSApplication.current.bundleURL` right? I get an error that there is no meember `current`.

Comment: Sorry my bad (typo) `NSRunningApplication.current.bundleURL ?? ""`

Comment: @LeoDabus That’s excellent. It gives me something to work from. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a the list of the running applications, filter then by there bundle identifiers and then filter them again the ones that are not equal to the current one:

```
let sameBundleIdentifiers = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications.filter({$0.bundleIdentifier == (Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "")})

print("sameBundleIdentifiers", sameBundleIdentifiers.count)

let filtered = sameBundleIdentifiers.filter {$0 != NSRunningApplication.current }
```